# Problems installing m2eclipse plugin to Indigo: 'bundle org.eclipse.zest.core 0.0.0' could not be found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

From Indigo Available Software screen I select maven integration for Eclipse , then Next. got the following error message (blank lines added for readability):

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>   Software being installed: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required) 0.12.1.20110112-1712 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.12.1.20110112-1712)
>
> Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Editors) 0.12.1.20110112-1712 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.editor 0.12.1.20110112-1712) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.zest.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
>
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
>    From: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required) 0.12.1.20110112-1712 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.12.1.20110112-1712)
>    To: org.maven.ide.eclipse.editor [0.12.1.20110112-1712]

Answer (score 5):

You probably have an old update site. Version 1.0 is already available and your log shows 0.12.x. Check: http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/

Use: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases